# How to write uppercase bold italic letters matplotlib using LaTeX?

Tags: python, matplotlib, latex

I want to have the text shown in the image [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ijn3R.png) in a plot (this is taken from Rubidium 87 D Line Data - Daniel A. Steck, page 23). It's a simple equation involving an **uppercase letter, in bold italics, with font Computer Modern**. So far I've tried

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.rcParams["text.usetex"] = True
plt.rcParams["text.latex.preamble"].join([
    r"\usepackage{bm}",
    r"\usepackage{amsmath}"])


fig, ax = plt.subplots()

# Not bold
ax.text(0, 0.5, r"$F=0$", fontsize=18)

# Not italic
ax.text(0.2, 0.5, r"$\mathbf{F=0}$", fontsize=18)

# Not italic, not the correct font
ax.text(0.4, 0.5, r"\textit{\textbf{F}}=0", fontsize=18)

# Returns an error from LaTeX
ax.text(0.6, 0.5, r"$\bm{F}=0$", fontsize=18)

# Returns an error from LaTeX
ax.text(0.8, 0.5, r"$\boldsymbol{F}=0$", fontsize=18)
```

I'm using pdfTeX, Version 3.141592653-2.6-1.40.23 (TeX Live 2021/W32TeX) to display the equations.

Comment: Which error are you getting?

Comment: For \bm I get:

! Undefined control sequence.
<recently read> \bm 
                    
l.18 {\sffamily $\bm
                    {F}=2$}

I have a similar error with \boldsymbol.

Comment: I cannot reproduce the error. Please provide a [minimal working example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: I can reproduce the errors. Maybe check if your TeX install has those packages, e.g. `bm`.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't seem like you want to achieve anything TeX specific, so you can slip away with doing it all by tweaking your rcParams and the rest when calling `plt.text`

```
>>> plt.rc('font', **{'family': 'serif', 'serif': ['Computer Modern']})
>>> plt.text(0,0,text.upper(), fontweight='bold', fontstyle='italic')
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to make it run. For some reason the preamble was not set properly. The following code did the job:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.rcParams["text.usetex"] = True
plt.rcParams["text.latex.preamble"] = r"\usepackage{bm}"

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.text(0.6, 0.5, r"$\bm{F}\:\mathbf{=0}$", fontsize=18)
```